# How to remove all dropdown option and replace new option by only NAME attibute given?

Tags: javascript, jquery

need some help for jquery.

How can i remove all dropdown option and replace new option?

Note : Only **Name attribute** used, **No ID attribute** used in select tag.

```
<tr id="payment_currency_tr">
    <TD class="prompt">     
        Payment currency* 
    </TD>
    <TD  class="formdata">
  <SELECT name="payment_currency" onchange="" style="" >  <!-- to clear this option and replace to SGD option only.
   <OPTION value="">
       <OPTION VALUE="USD" >USD       
            <OPTION SELECTED SELECTED VALUE="CHF" >CHF    
            <OPTION VALUE="SGD" >SGD 
      </SELECT> 
    </TD>
</tr>
```

I try below script but not work
1)

```
   msg = 'SGD';
   js_option = '<option value="' + msg + '">' + msg + '</option>';

    jQuery("#payment_currency_tr")
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append(js_option)
    .val(msg)
```

2)

```
 msg = 'SGD';
   Var d = document.getElementsByName('payment_currency')[0];
       d.options[0].option = msg;
       d.options[0].value = msg;
```

I know there is a way to change by using ID attibute but too bad i can't used it due to the table structure is generated via some cfm custom tag and unable to modify

```
document.getElementById("payment_currency").options.length = 0;
                    jQuery("#payment_currency").children().end().append(js_option);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simply,

```
msg = 'SGD';
js_option = '<option value="' + msg + '">' + msg + '</option>';
$('select[name="payment_currency"]').html(js_option)//set new html,replace previous options
                                    .val(msg); // sel msg as selected option
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/52MCL/)

or you can try

```
jQuery("#payment_currency_tr").find('select')// find drop down
                              .html(js_option)
                              .val(msg);
```

[Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/52MCL/1/)